# How do I add new tabs with text areas dynamically when button is clicked?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

as a project for myself I have decided to create a text editor and on some advice about code structure and user design I have abandoned creating new instances of the editor when the "New" menu item is clicked by the user. Instead, I have decided to use "Tabs" using `JTabbedPane`. I can setup the first tab ok but I can't seem to figure out how to create a new tab dynamically next to the one(s) already there. Has anyone any experience with `JTabbedPane` or any ideas on how I would implement this.

Here's the code:

```
public class Editor extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

//===============================================
// FIELDS
//===============================================

    // Menus
    private JMenu fileMenu, editMenu;

    // Menu Items
    private JMenuItem newFile, openFile, saveFile, saveAsFile, pageSetup, printFile, exit;
    private JMenuItem undo, redo, cut, copy, paste, selectAll;

    // Menu Bar
    private JMenuBar menuBar;

    // New tab
    private JTabbedPane tab;
    private NewTab newTab;

    // Text Area
    private JScrollPane scroll;
    private JTextArea textArea;

//===============================================
// CONSTRUCTOR
//===============================================

    public Editor() {
        super("SchongeEdit");

        // Set initial size of the window
        setSize(800, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // Set the default close operation (exit when it gets closed)
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        

        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 5));
        newTab = new NewTab();
        tab = newTab.createTab(createTextArea());
        getContentPane().add(tab);

        add(createMenuBar(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

//===============================================
// METHODS
//===============================================

    // Creates the menu bar for holding the menus
    private JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.add(fileMenu());
        menuBar.add(editMenu());

        return menuBar;
    }

    // Creates the text area in a scroll pane
    private JScrollPane createTextArea() {
        // Set text area and default font
        textArea = new JTextArea("", 0, 0);
        textArea.setEditable(true);
        textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 10, 0, 0));
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        return scroll;
    }
}
```

I have left out the `fileMenu()` and `editMenu()` methods as they aren't necessary and will only clog up space

Here's my NewTab() class:

```
public class NewTab {

    // Tabs
    private JTabbedPane tab;
    private String newTabName = "New Tab";

// Creates a new tabbed pane with a text area
    protected JTabbedPane createTab(JScrollPane scroll) {
        tab = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        tab.addTab(newTabName, scroll);

        return tab;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see any problems with your `NewTab.createTab(JScrollPane)` method.  It seems to me that your code could tall that method to create another tab on the same `JTabbedPane`.  I don't see anything wrong with your code design - it seems to me you'd have an `ActionListener` on the button that would call that method in order to create new tabs.

Comment: @Daniel I have tried `tab.addTab("New Tab", newTab.createTab(scroll));` but that just creates a tab within a tab (tabception, sorry!) and even at that the tab inside the other tab is the only one that will work

Comment: You're NewTab class should return the JScrollPane, not a new JTabbedPane, you then should add this to you're existing tabbed pane, preferably with some kind of name to identify it

Comment: @MadProgrammer perfect works like a dream, thanks! If you'd like to put it in as an answer I can close this thread off, if that matters. If it doesn't then no worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basic problem is, you're adding a new `JTabbedPane` to your existing `JTabbedPane`.

Instead of your `NewTab` returning a new `JTabbedPane`, you should have it return the component that is to act as the view for the tab and the tabs name, for example...

```
public class NewTab {

    private String tabName = "New Tab";

    // Creates a new tabbed pane with a text area
    protected JComponent createTab() {
        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ta);

        return ta;
    }

    public String getTabName() {
        // Could be used to hold the file name, for example
        return tabName;
    }

}
```

Then you would use this to add the view to an existing `JTabbedPane`

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that you'd typically add `Panel`s to the tabs of a `JTabbedPane`, although I think `JTabbedPane.addTab(Container)` accepts any type of `Container`.  [The tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) provides a couple examples (although perhaps those aren't practical for your needs).

I'd probably create a new instance (`JPanel`, `JScrollPane`, or other container) each time I add a new tab, so the same content doesn't show up on multiple tabs.